# Как ограничить доступ к лишним файлам нас сайте (по прямой ссылке)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

Обычный сайт на PHP. Есть стартовая страница `login.php` и основная `main.php`. К ним прилагаются несколько файлов `css` и `js`. При вводе прямой ссылки на `main.php` просто делаю переадресацию на `login.php` если пользователь не зарегистрировался. А как ограничить доступ по прямой ссылке на файлы `css` и `js`? Пытался использовать `.htaccess` - `Deny from all`, доступ к файлам закрывается, но закрывается и для меня, и для `php` скриптов, отображение стилей слетает и так далее.

Comment: «А как ограничить доступ по прямой ссылке» ... зачем?